# Using '<import resource=' on multiple beans profiles in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

In my application-context.xml, I am using

```
<import resource="classpath*:com/companyName/projectName/dao/dao-beans.xml"/>
```

In the dao-beans.xml file, I am using

```
<beans profile="profile1;profile2;profile">
    <import resource="classpath*:com/companyName/projectName/dao/spring/xyz/xyz-dao-beans.xml" />
</beans>
```

I am confused as to what does this part mean -

```
<beans profile="profile1;profile2;profile">
```

Does this mean that all 3 profiles should be active for all beans inside xyz-dao-beans.xml to be imported, or even if either of the 3 is active, the xyz dao beans will be imported?

Comment: It is an `and` clause but afaik should be `,` separated and not `;` separated.

Comment: well this is also another doubt. Semi colon works, but what is the difference if I put comma vs semicolon?

Comment: Apparently nothing.

Comment: Are you sure this is an `and` relation and not an `or`. Why would spring give such a feature. Somehow I feel `or` makes better sense.

Comment: It isn't it is an `and`.

Comment: Okay, but then I have another doubt. In my integration test, i wrote `@ActiveProfiles("profile2")`. Still the beans inside the xyz dao beans got imported. How did that happen? Did I not have to activate all 3 profiles?

Comment: Also, what about this new answer, it states an `or` relation

Comment: Apparently I should read up on the changes to that, originally it was an and (somewhere in Spring 2.5) but changed when allowing to write more complex expressions (also with the exclusions etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html):

> `This is analogous to the behavior in Spring XML: if the profile attribute of the beans element is supplied e.g., <beans profile="p1,p2">, the beans element will not be parsed unless at least profile 'p1' or 'p2' has been activated. Likewise, if a @Component or @Configuration class is marked with @Profile({"p1", "p2"}), that class will not be registered or processed unless at least profile 'p1' or 'p2' has been activated.`